# Конвертировать DOCX в PDF на Python

Tags: python

Мне необходимо конвертировать файлы Word в PDF.
Необходимо найти решение, которое позволит осуществить эту конвертацию без учета программ, установленных у пользователя. Возможно, есть библиотеки или API, которые могут помочь в этом?

1. docx2pdf и COM automation требует установленного офиса
2. python-docx + PyFPDF теряется форматирование

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь и советы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так DOCX в PDF или Word в PDA? В заголовке написано одно, в вопросе - другое...

Comment: Интересует конвертация Word в PDF. 
Проблема с которой столкнулся это существующие библиотеки зависят от установленных программ. Т.е. конвертация происходит посредством Word, openOffice  этого хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: Без офиса нормально док не отрендерить. Можно попробовать либреофис в хеадлесс режиме

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Варианты Микрософт офис или либреофис, опенофис известны. Проблема в том что они используют программы установленные у пользователя, что вызывает от них зависимость, а этого хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: Вариант - использовать веб-сервис. Либо существующий либо свой.